# Four arguments passed to 'for' which requires three arguments for a 'for' loop

Tags: r

I am trying to add a new column, currency, to df "myfile".

The contents of that column are conditional like if the year column fulfills this condition then the new column has this value, else another value.

When I tried *if else* without the loop, it says >1, so I guessed *if else* couldn’t work for a vector with multiple elements, I could use a *for* loop, but then this error showed:

```
myfile$currency <- myfile %>% for (i in year) {if(year>2000){print("Latest")}else{"Oldest"}}
Error in for (. in i) year : 4 arguments passed to 'for' which requires 3
```

Comment: sorry i tried this
myfile$currency <- myfile %>% for (yr in year) {if(yr>2000){print("Latest")}else{"Oldest"}} but same error

Comment: You can't pipe data into a `for` loop. Take a look at `ifelse` instead. For example `myfile$currency <- ifelse(myfile$year>2000, "Latest", "Oldest") `

Comment: As an R beginner, if you feel like you need to use a for loop, you most likely have identified an area where you have not yet learned to think in R. For loops--especially foreach loops--do have their place in R especially when running Monte Carlo models and such like, but almost never are needed for general data wrangling

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ifelse` in `mutate`. See the documentation for [dpylr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dplyr).

```
library(dplyr)
myfile <- myfile %>%
mutate(
  currency = ifelse(year > 2000, "latest", "oldest")
)
```

If you have more conditions, see `case_when`.

Or you can do something like this:

```
myfile$currency[myfile$year > 2000] <-  "latest"
myfile$currency[myfile$year <= 2000] <-  "oldest"
```

Comment: great
second one is very convenient
thanks very much